# Swift: Set label & custom parameters in tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is a build up of a previous question.

I have an array defined like this:

```
var items = [[String:String]]()
```

This data is updated dynamically from a json file

```
for (_,bands) in json {
    for (_,bname) in bands {
       let bnameID = bname["id"].stringValue
       let bnameName = bname["Title"].stringValue

       let dict  = ["id":bnameID,"Title":bnameName]
       self.items.append(dict as [String : String])


       self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

This is the output when I print the items array

```
[["Title": "The Kooks", "id": "2454"], 
["Title": "The Killers", "id": "34518"], 
["Title": "Madonna", "id": "9"]]
```

## Question 1:

In this function

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }
```

How do I get the cell labels to show the items that are in the 'Title' section of the array?

## Question 2

In this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { }
```

How do I get the value 'id' from the array that corresponds to which cell has been clicked? so for example, if **The Killers** cell was clicked then I could set a variable with the value of: **34518**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `title`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print(items[indexPath.row]["Title"])
}
```

To get the `id`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 

    print(items[indexPath.row]["id"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was so close, I was doing: print(items["id"][indexPath.row]) :S

Comment: Oh! `items["id"]` just works for `Dictionary`. But for array you need to specify the index every time, so please take care of that next time!

Answer (score 1):

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)!
    let dictn : NSDictionary = items[indexPath.section] as! NSDictionary

    cell.textLabel?.text = dictn.objectForKey("Title") as? String
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1-**

You can fetch the title of the item in your items array using the row value of the indexPath:

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
//Fetch the id
let title = item["Title"]!
```

**Answer to Question 2-**

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
//Fetch the id
let id = item["id"]!
```

So in either cases, you will be picking up the associated item from your items array using the row value of the indexPath.